Conditions for a Hermitian matrix to be positive definite
It's a question from chapter 7c of Linear algebra done right 4th edition.

Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $e_1 \cdots e_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$. Prove that T is a positive operator if and only if there exist $v_1 \cdots v_n \in V$ such that $$<Te_k, e_j>=<v_k, v_j>$$

Here is where I've progressed so far:
Prove the sufficient part ($\Rightarrow$): since $T$ is positive then $<Te_k, e_j>=<\sqrt{T}e_k, \sqrt{T}e_j>$, by letting $v_i=\sqrt{T}e_i$ complete the proof of $=>$.
Prove the necessary part: ($\Leftarrow$) let $v$ be an arbitrary vector of the form $v=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ie_i$, we need to prove $\langle Tv, v \rangle \geq 0$ by expanding the expression with the basis and the conditions given in problem, it's equivalent to prove $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i|^2||v_i||^2+\sum_{i\neq j}a_i\bar{a_j}\langle v_i, v_j \rangle \geq 0$$
Observe that $a_i\bar{a_j} \langle v_i, v_j \rangle$ and $a_j\bar{a_i} \langle v_j, v_i \rangle$ is conjugate to each other. It's equivalent to prove $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i|^2||v_i||^2+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}Re(a_i\bar{a_j}\langle v_i, v_j \rangle) \geq 0$$
The question is how can I progress further from here to complete the proof of <= part?

Set $u = \sum a_k e_k$, you get
$$\begin{align*}
\langle Tu,u\rangle &= \sum_{i,j}a_i\bar{a}_j\langle Te_i,e_j\rangle = \sum_{i,j}a_i\bar{a}_j\langle v_i,v_j\rangle = \langle \sum_{i}a_iv_i,\sum_j a_jv_j\rangle = \left\| \sum_k a_k v_k \right\|^2 \geq 0
\end{align*}$$
You were almost there, you just went a bit too complicated, in fact you already had done the hard part.
You may want to prove that $T$ is hermitian, you only need to prove it on elements of the basis:
$$\langle Te_i,e_j \rangle = \langle v_i,v_j\rangle = \langle v_j,v_i\rangle = \langle Te_j,e_i\rangle = \langle e_j,T^*e_i\rangle = \langle T^* e_i,e_j\rangle.$$
